# Remove Lines Containing using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to create Remove Lines Containing using jquery, here is my code:

```
<body>
Search lines for:
<input type="text" id="search-lines" value="Sometimes|relevance|understand" style="width:100%; margin-top:10px;" />
<button id="process">Process!</button>
<textarea id="input" style="width:100%; margin-top:10px; height:150px; resize:none;" wrap="off">Sometimes to understand a word's
meaning you need more than a definition.
At Your Dictionary we try to give you all of the tools
you need to really understand what the word means.
Seeing the word in a sentence can
provide more context and relevance.</textarea>
<textarea id="containing-output" rows="4" style="width:100%; margin-top:10px; height:150px; resize:none;" wrap="off"></textarea>
<textarea id="not-contating-output" rows="4" style="width:100%; margin-top:10px; height:150px; resize:none;" wrap="off"></textarea>
</body>
```

this is how it works:

Search lines for:

> **Sometimes**|**relevance**|**understand**

Text Lines Input:

> **Sometimes** to understand a word's
>
> meaning you need more than a definition.
>
> At Your Dictionary we try to give you all of the tools
>
> you need to really **understand** what the word means.
>
> Seeing the word in a sentence can
>
> provide more context and **relevance**.

Containing Lines Output:

> **Sometimes** to understand a word's
>
> you need to really **understand** what the word means.
>
> provide more context and **relevance**.

Not-Containing Lines Output:

> meaning you need more than a definition.
>
> At Your Dictionary we try to give you all of the tools
>
> Seeing the word in a sentence can

Comment: Where is your current javascript code??

Comment: Yeah you need to try something. We're not supposed to develop stuff for you, but just help you when your code doesn't work. For the time being, there's no code at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an array

```
var unwantedwords= array(
//create an array of your list of words
)
```

var sometext = "Sometimes to understand a word's"; // here is your string

then loop through the array and check for those values and remove it from your string

```
for (index = 0; index < unwantedwords.length; ++index) {
var word = unwantedwords[index ];
var check = sometext.indexOf(word)
  if(check !== false)
   {
     removedwordstring = sometext.replace(word,'');
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this one?

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#process").click(function(){
    var searchCriteria = $("#search-lines").val().split("|");
      // You can split with \n or .
    var data = $('#input').val().split("\n");
    var matched = [];
    var unMatched = [];
    $.each(data, function (i, j) {
        $.each(searchCriteria, function (index, value) {
            if (j.indexOf(value) > 0) {
                matched.push(j.replace(value, "<b>" + value + "</b>"));
            } else {
                unMatched.push(j);
            }
        });
    });
    $("#containing-output").val(matched);
    $("#not-contating-output").val(unMatched);
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
Search lines for:
<input type="text" id="search-lines" value="Sometimes|relevance|understand" style="width:100%; margin-top:10px;" />
<button id="process">Process!</button>
<textarea id="input" style="width:100%; margin-top:10px; height:150px; resize:none;" wrap="off">Sometimes to understand a word's
meaning you need more than a definition.
At Your Dictionary we try to give you all of the tools
you need to really understand what the word means.
Seeing the word in a sentence can
provide more context and relevance.</textarea>
<textarea id="containing-output" rows="4" style="width:100%; margin-top:10px; height:150px; resize:none;" wrap="off"></textarea>
<textarea id="not-contating-output" rows="4" style="width:100%; margin-top:10px; height:150px; resize:none;" wrap="off"></textarea>
</body>
```